# selecting observations based on a condition depended on a grouped variable

Tags: r

I have a question that I am hoping some will help me answer. I have a data set ordered by parasites and year, that looks something like this (the actual dataset is much larger):

```
    parasites      year       samples      
    1000          2000        11  
    910           2000        22          
    878           2000        13  
    999           2002        64
    910           2002        75  
    710           2002        16  
    890           2004        29  
    810           2004        10  
    789           2004         9  
    876           2005        120   
    750           2005         12  
    624           2005        157
```

what I would like to do is, for every year, I want to select the 2 samples with the highest number of parasites, to give me an output that looks like this:

```
    parasites      year        samples    
    1000           2000         11   
    910            2000         22  
    999            2002         64  
    910            2002         75  
    890            2004         29  
    810            2004         10  
    876            2005        120  
    750            2005         12
```

I am new to programming as a whole and still trying to find my way around R. can someone please explain to me how I would go about this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about with `data.table`:

```
parasites<-read.table(header=T,text="parasites     year      samples
1000          2000        11
910           2000        22
878           2000        13
999           2002        64
910           2002        75
710           2002        16
890           2004        29
810           2004        10
789           2004         9
876           2005        120
750           2005         12
624           2005        157")
```

**EDIT  - sorry sorted by parasites, not samples**

```
require(data.table)
data.table(parasites)[,.SD[order(-parasites)][1:2],by="year"]
```

Note `.SD` is the sub-table for each `year` value as set in `by=`

```
year parasites samples
1: 2000      1000      11
2: 2000       910      22
3: 2002       999      64
4: 2002       910      75
5: 2004       890      29
6: 2004       810      10
7: 2005       876     120
8: 2005       750      12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a R-base solution (if you need it):

```
data = data.frame("parasites"=c(1000,910,878,999,910,710,890,910,789,876,750,624),
                  "year"=c(2000,2000,2000,2002,2002,2002,2004,2004,2004,2005,2005,2005),
                  "samples"=c(11,22,13,64,75,16,29,10,9,120,12,157))

data = data[order(data$year,data$samples),]

data_list = lapply(unique(data$year),function(x) (tail(data[data$year==x,],n=2)))

final_data = do.call(rbind, Map(as.data.frame,data_list))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: it's a bit more complex, but works as well. Thanks a lot for your help.